# iOS 14: call controls not displayed in lock screen

Tags: iphone, ios

Seems like I’m missing something obvious but can’t seem to find an answer.

Before upgrading to iOS 14, 3rd party apps like Teams would show call controls like mute, hang up etc, on the Lock Screen, while in a call. Now it seems the best I can do is click the green bar, unlock the phone, find the call controls I want inside the app somewhere.

I’ve tried changing the Incoming Calls setting to full screen, swiping every which way on the Lock Screen, no luck.

It looks like people have asked similar questions in the past when the call controls screen behavior changed in previous iOS releases...

iPhone SE 2020 with iOS 14

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue on my iPhone XR

Comment: I'm also having this issue on an iPhone 7 Plus. I miss this feature dearly because I use the large buttons on the call controls screen to mute/unmute myself during Teams meetings.

Comment: And I use that when using my iDevice strictly for the voice part and need to control that, with other all interactions (e.g. screen sharing) occurring on the desktop machine: for one, there's really no need for both devices to be receiving the screen sharing feed!

Answer (score 9):

I found perfectly working WORKAROUND:

During Microsoft Teams meeting, just go to home screen, start dialing any number via built-in Phone app and stop even after 1 second. Your Teams meeting won't dissconnect, it will just pause. After that, when You go back to Teams and lock the screen, call controls will appear every time! Simple as that!!!

Of course You have to repeat those steps on every new Teams meeting.
I hope you find this guide useful.

Comment: I love, that you spread your answer throughout the internet :D No, really. I mean it.

Comment: I did something similar: I called the iOS 14 iPhone from another line, and let it ring until the call shows up on the iPhone. After hanging up the other line, the iPhone call controls show up on the lock screen. That way my original call isn't interrupted.

Comment: Dear Microsoft and Apple: see what you are making us do! So please get your act together.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing this issue with calls on third party apps, but the lock screen controls show for the native phone app. I haven't tried FaceTime audio or other Apple apps. It's possible that the third party apps need to be updated for iOS 14.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue on my iPhone 11 but noticed something today - if I'm just on with 1 person (ie: someone calls me via Teams) and I lock my screen it does seem to show up as a phone call in the lock screen (as it used to). My sample size is 1 here as I haven't had a chance to try it again but it could just be an app issue as others have pointed out if it's somehow classifying "group" calls as something different in the new OS?